# How can I track my Chromebook?

Tags: chromebook

According to https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/7177579, you can track a lost Chromebook via the "Find your phone" section of Google My Account. However, my Chromebook doesn't show up there. I'm logged in, and it shows my other devices. It's an HP Chromebook 14 G4. How do I make it show up on the device list?

Comment: When you say you're logged in, do you mean you're logged into the Chromebook with that same Google account? Is this a managed device owned by your school or employer?

Answer (score 3):

From the linked article, your next steps are:

> - Check that you're signed in to the right Google Account on the device you're currently using.
> - Your lost device needs to be signed in to your Google Account on a Google app, like Gmail or YouTube.
> - Windows, Mac, and Linux computers aren't listed under "Find your phone."

Comment: I have read the article and followed the steps. My question is that the steps in the articles don't work, so I would like to know if anyone knows why?

Comment: The steps in the article work, what is not clear at this stage is whether the Google account on the Chromebook and the one you are trying to track it with are the same.

Comment: So, is this a personal device, or is it managed and/or owned by an employer or school?

Comment: @MichaelFrank Sorry, I never received a notification. The accounts are one and the same.

Comment: @music2myear It's a personal device.

Answer (score 1):

If the Chromebook is a personal device, you cannot do anything other than cause it to log out of your account.
Unlike phones, Chromebooks do not have a GPS chip so cannot be tracked to locations other than the Country (and sometimes the City) the Chromebooks is located in.
An organsiation that is the registered owner of a Chromebook have more options. However, an unscupilous person can simply do a PowerWash and that is the end of that organisations control.
The best way to secure you Chromebook is to ENGRAVE "NOT FOR RESALE", your name and contact number on lid and base of the Chromebook.

Comment: "Chromebooks do not have a GPS chip so cannot be tracked to locations other than the Country (and sometimes the City)" - this is incorrect, many devices can be tracked via Wi-Fi alone, such as Windows laptops.

Comment: @Micheal Kolber. A Chomebook is not a Windows laptop and although Google tracks these by Wi-Fi, the granularity is Country/City as posted.